# How to get return value of sem_wait()?

Tags: c, process, posix, semaphore

I have a program that's supposed to let two processes alternate between doing a certain task. After the fifth time the child process executes its task it has to destroy a semaphore and the parent process is supposed to stop because of it.

This sounded fairly easy at first, but I'm having difficulty capturing the return value of the `sem_wait()` function.

Here's my file:

```
#include "Part2Defs.h"

int main() {

  FILE *fptr = 0;

  sem_t *child  = mmap(0, sizeof(sem_t), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
                       MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

  sem_t *parent = mmap(0, sizeof(sem_t), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
                 MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

  /* save the number that we'll be writing to the file */
  int number = 1, removed = 0;

  sem_init(child,  1, 1);
  sem_init(parent, 1, 0);


  fptr = fopen(BUFFER, "r+");
  if(fptr == 0) {
    printf("An error occurred while opening the file\n");
  }

  fprintf(fptr, "%d", number);

  fclose(fptr);

  int pID = fork();

  if(pID == 0) {

    /* do this FOREVER. */
    while(1) {

      /* I was hoping to get the return value here */
      if(sem_wait(parent) == 0) {

      /* open the file */
      fptr = fopen(BUFFER, "r+");

      printf("B. The number [] was modified by parent\n");

      fclose(fptr);
      sem_post(child);
      }
      else {
        printf("--parent-- waiting for new number to be READ: Identifier removed");
      }
    } 

    return 0;
  }
  else if(pID > 0) {

    /* make a counter to go from 0 to 5 */
    int i = 0;
    while(1) {

      sem_wait(child);

     if(i++ == 5) {
        /* delete the semaphore */
        sem_destroy(parent);

        printf("Semaphore removed\n");
        break;
      }
       /* open the file */
      fptr = fopen(BUFFER, "r+");

      printf("A. The number [] was modified by child\n");

      fclose(fptr);
      sem_post(parent);
   }

    return 0;
  }
  else {
    printf("There was an error creating the fork.\n");
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

Here's my output:

```
A. The number [] was modified by child
B. The number [] was modified by parent
A. The number [] was modified by child
B. The number [] was modified by parent
A. The number [] was modified by child
B. The number [] was modified by parent
A. The number [] was modified by child
B. The number [] was modified by parent
A. The number [] was modified by child
B. The number [] was modified by parent
Semaphore removed
```

Which is almost exactly what I was hoping for, except the parent process never ended with the message containing the error.

BY THE WAY: this is homework, but I'm supposedly not allowed to add the homework tag on my own post because of my lack of reputation.

Comment: Why the downvote to my question? I haven't been able to find this question asked anywhere, and I thought it was perfectly reasonable to ask...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_destroy.3.html :

"Destroying a semaphore that other processes or threads are currently
       blocked on (in sem_wait(3)) produces undefined behavior."

I found a way to use one of the semaphores as a flag to tell the parent when it's done.

```
#include "Part2Defs.h"


int main() {

  FILE *fptr = 0;

  sem_t *child  = mmap(0, sizeof(sem_t), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
                       MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

  sem_t *parent = mmap(0, sizeof(sem_t), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
                 MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

  /* save the number that we'll be writing to the file */
  int number = 1, removed = 0;

  sem_init(child,  1, 0);
  sem_init(parent, 1, 0);


  fptr = fopen(BUFFER, "r+");
  if(fptr == 0) {
    printf("An error occurred while opening the file\n");
  }

  fprintf(fptr, "%d", number);

  fclose(fptr);

  int pID = fork();

  if(pID == 0) {

    /* do this FOREVER. */
    while(1) {
      sem_post(child);
      sem_wait(parent);
      if(!sem_trywait(child))
          break;
      /* open the file */
      fptr = fopen(BUFFER, "r+");

      printf("B. The number [] was modified by parent\n");
      fflush(stdout);

      fclose(fptr);
    }

    sem_destroy(child);
    sem_destroy(parent);

    printf("--parent-- waiting for new number to be READ: Identifier removed");
    return 0;
  }
  else if(pID > 0) {

    /* make a counter to go from 0 to 5 */
    int i = 0;
    while(1) {
      sem_wait(child);

     if(i++ == 5) {
        sem_post(child);
        sem_post(parent);
        //Signal the parent that it's done by adding one to child.

        printf("Semaphore removed\n");
        break;
      }
       /* open the file */
      fptr = fopen(BUFFER, "r+");

      printf("A. The number [] was modified by child\n");
      fflush(stdout);

      fclose(fptr);

      sem_post(parent);
   }

    return 0;
  }
  else {
    printf("There was an error creating the fork.\n");
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: I read that too, but I also read this: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Fapis%2Fipcsemde.htm and according to that: "Any threads that have blocked from calling sem_wait() or sem_wait_np() on the semaphore will unblock and return an [EINVAL] or [EDESTROYED] error." That's what I was relying on

Comment: @AbeFehr Lol, but apparently that's not happening, given that the code doesn't work as expected. I think I came up with a something that does that; it uses the error returned from `sem_post()` instead to end the program, although I had to change the control flow a bit to get it to run in the right spot. I'm not too sure you actually need two semaphores either, seems like one would do

Comment: I JUST can't quite get the right output with that, but using the sem_post()'s error is a really good idea. I'm going to really have to think about that for a while, it's a very good headscratcher...and my prof actually requires us to use two semaphores in this assignment, even though it's unnecessary

Comment: Got it! Change the appropriate line to `sem_init(child, 1, 0);` Edit: Actually, it's still not working correctly..

Comment: no worries, I've been working on this for hours and I haven't really had any luck. If you can't get it, I'm sure no one else in my class will either. Thanks for trying, and as soon as the question is mature enough to allow me to I'll accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Got it! I used a sem_trywait() that fails every time unless the child process post()s to child before post()ing to parent, so it's basically using one of the semaphores as a flag.

Answer (score 0):

`sem_wait`'s return value only reflects its seccess/failure in acquiring the lock.  If you want communication between processes, you need another mechanism (for example, shared memory).